# Bluebird — a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

First of all, I know that I have to `return` promises to avoid this warning. I've also tried returning `null` as suggested [here in the docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it). Consider this piece of code, I'm using it in Mongoose's pre-save hook, but I've experienced this warning in other places:

```
var Story = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);

StorySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var story = this;

    // Fetch all stories before save to automatically assign
    // some variable, avoiding conflict with other stories
    return Story.find().then(function(stories) {

        // Some code, then set story.somevar value
        story.somevar = somevar;
        return null;
    }).then(next).catch(next); // <-- this line throws warning
});
```

I've also tried (initially) this way:

```
        story.somevar = somevar;
        return next(); // <-- this line throws warning
    }).catch(next);
```

But it doesn't work either. Oh, and I have to mention, that I use Bluebird:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Not a duplicate of [A promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948597/a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it), the guy forgot to return a promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluebird Unhandled rejection error from successful jquery ajax POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948597/bluebird-unhandled-rejection-error-from-successful-jquery-ajax-post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is pretty much using a `next` callback at all, which calls functions that create promises without returning them. Ideally the hooks just needed to return promises instead of taking callbacks.

You should be able to prevent the warning by using

```
.then(function(result) {
    next(null, result);
    return null;
}, function(error) {
    next(error);
    return null;
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I've changed a bit to call `next(error);` to pass the error further to handlers. I don't quite get the part about "the hooks just needed to return promises instead of taking callbacks", where can I read about that? The more I write Node.js + promises code, the less I understand it :D

Comment: I mean mongoose should've changed it's API so that hooks could just return a promise instead of having to call a `next` callback.