# Bluebird warning - a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bluebird, superagent

First off, I know that I have to return promises to avoid this warning. I've also tried returning `null` as suggested [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it) but it does not work. This is my piece of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import request from 'superagent-bluebird-promise';

function loadCountry(url, countryId) {
  return request.get(`${url}/countries/${countryId}`).set('Accept', 'application/json').
    then(response => response.body.name || response.body.id).catch(errors => null);
}

class AddressCountry extends Component {

  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    loadCountry(this.props.actionUrl, this.props.countryId).then(country => {
      this.setState({ country: country });
    });
  }
}
```

I tried returning `null` after the line `this.setState({ country: country });` but it did not work.
This is the error I get:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler at eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:1201:1), <anonymous>:65:16 but was not returned from it
    at new Promise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:2064:1), <anonymous>:2715:26)
    at <anonymous>
From previous event:
    at Request.promise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:728:1), <anonymous>:72:10)
    at loadCountry (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:4762:1), <anonymous>:25:157)
    at AddressCountry.componentDidMount (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:4762:1), <anonymous>:51:7)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:3959:1), <anonymous>:77:12)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:4078:1), <anonymous>:62:26)
    at enqueueUpdate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:1103:1), <anonymous>:26:16)
    at SupplierAddressEditor.ReactComponent.setState (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:1201:1), <anonymous>:65:16)
From previous event:
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:3959:1), <anonymous>:77:12)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/supplier/static/bundle.js:4078:1), <anonymous>:62:26)
```

PS: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861736/bluebird-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it) nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948597/a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise from loadCountry() in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
        return loadCountry(this.props.actionUrl, this.props.countryId).then(country => this.setState({ country }));
      }
```

Comment: I have don this but still shows the same warning :(